# React-Redux: visualize elements array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning to use react and redux.

So I have a little bit of questions:

I have structured in this way:

**reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
    meetings: []
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'MEETINGS_LIST':
            return [...state.meetings, action.meetings];
        default: 
            return state;
    }    
}
export default reducer;
```

**action.js**

```
export const meetingsList = (meeting) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(
            res => res.json(),
            error => console.log('An error occurred.', error))
        .then(meetings => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'MEETINGS_LIST',
                meetings: meetings
            })
        })
    }
}
```

It's right to do the fetch in the actions.js? Or I should do in the reducers?

Anyway my problem is in main page,

```
class MeetingsList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.meetingsList();
}


render(){
    console.log(this.props.meetings)
    return(
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {meetings: state}
};

function mapDdispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        meetingsList: (meetings) => dispatch(meetingsList(meetings))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDdispatchToProps)(MeetingsList)
```

I would like to print the contents of the props on the screen. It is an array [10], I had thought of using a map to be able to print every single array, but every time I try it tells me that it is impossible to use the map of an undefined. How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You're defining the `initialState` as an object. On the `MEETINGS_LIST` type you're returning an array.
2. After a second dispatch of `MEETINGS_LIST`, you're spreading `state.meetings` which is undefined (because state isn't an object anymore)
3. You're dispatching `{ meetings: meetings }` where `meetings` is an array (because you're retrieving a list of users at this moment). But you're not spreading that array in your `MEETINGS_LIST` handler.

So:

1. Change `(state = initialState)` to `(state = [])`.
2. Change your 'MEETINGS_LIST' handler to `return [...state, ...action.meetings];`
3. Now you can loop over your meetings:

```
const elements = this.props.meetings.map((meeting) => <li key={meeting.id}>{meeting.title}</li>);

return <ul>{elements}</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You help me a lot! Only a problem now I receive this error: 

`state.meetings is not iterable` in the reducers.js.

Maybe because I have done `export const reducer = (state = [] , action) => {` And I don't use the `initialState = { meetings: [] }` ??

Comment: You're right. It should be `[...state, ...action.meetings]`, because the 'state' is now an array. I updated my answer

Comment: Ok after your edit I print the dot in the screen xD Just another question, the initialState = { meetings: [] } is declared but not used. How the reducer understand to use meetings: [] ?

Comment: @Jack23 then you would have to define your state as an object and use the properties of that object everywhere. You should view the redux documentation for that, there are some examples